# what if the returned inner function does not referenced by any variable...?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, scope, closures

I have known that the returned inner function can hold the outer function's variables, this feature is the so-called *closure*.

I also know that the returned inner function's scope chain would hold the outer function's *variable object*, so it can access the outer function's variable —— this also the basis of eating much memory, even lead to memory leak!

what makes me confusing is that, if the returned inner function does not referenced by any variable, just like this:

```
function outerFunc() {  
    var objA = new Object();  
    objA.propertyA = 'propertyA';  
    objA.propertyB = 'propertyB';  

    return function innerFunc() {
        return objA.propertyA + ' ' + objB.propertyB;
    }
}

outerFunc();
```

as you can see, I don't assign the returned innerFunc to any variable, I want to know if the innerFunc's scope chain will still created? And if the code above will still lead to memory wasting —— or even memory leak?

I remembered that a function's scope(or execution context) will only exists when the function being called, if it is, then the code above won't lead to memory leak? I am not sure, help me get out of it, help!

Comment: Whether you assign the return value to a variable or not doesn't have an impact on what happens to the function during definition (`outerFunc` cannot know what happens with the return value) . The only difference is that the function is immediately ready for garbage collection.

Comment: http://flightschool.acylt.com/devnotes/javascript-closures-and-memory-leaks/

Comment: Since it does nothing, it should be garbage collected just after the execution(at least I think it's this what happens)

Comment: @FelixKling,   thanks, but I still a little confuse. Okay, I still want to know, if the returned innerFunc is assigned to a variable but not be called, is the innerFunc's scope chain exists and as a result the outerFunc's variables keep in memory?

Comment: The inner scope of the function does not exist until the function is executed. But the generated function object will indeed have a reference to the execution context it was defined in (see http://es5.github.io/#x13 for details), i.e. the variables will be kept in memory. However, engines might optimize this process and already remove variables from memory if the function (the "closures") does not use them.